# Adobe Animate Air - android using phone proximity sensor to turn off screen?

Tags: flash, air, proximity

Still trying to explore action script.
Is there any way to access an android phone proximity sensor?  Would like to turn off the sceen using the output from the sensor.
Found the richardolsson / proximity-sensor-ane ( https://github.com/richardolsson/proximity-sensor-ane?search=1 ) TBH I don't have a clue what I am doing with it.
Any help would be awesom.  TIA

```
import se.riol.anes.proximitysensor.ProximitySensorInterface;

var proximity:ProximitySensorInterface;

proximity = new ProximitySensorInterface();
proximity.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, handleProximity);
proximity.start();

function handleProximity(ev:StatusEvent):void
{
    trace('proximity: ' + ev.level);
}
```

Comment: 1. You probably should start with learning, what is **ANE** and how do you add one to the project while working with the **IDE** you use. 2. The **trace** method is intended for the debug output, I don't remember now but it is either difficult or outright impossible to get the debug output on your mobile device. It is far easier to devise a **TextField** and output there all the things you want to see.